Which base image to use when dockerizing an API based on .NET Framework 4.6.1?
I have a Rest API based on .Net framework 4.6.1
I want to dockerize this API, but the problem is that I can't find a solution. All the solutions I found are almost all dedicated to other versions, for example, version 4.6.2, 4.7.0 etc. I used mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8 but my problem has not been solved so far.
This is the content of my Dockerfile:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8 AS base  
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot  

COPY ReclamationApp/ReclamationApp.csproj ./  
COPY ReclamationApp/packages.config ./  
COPY ReclamationApp.Utilities/ReclamationApp.Utilities.csproj ./ReclamationApp.Utilities/  
COPY ReclamationApp.Business/ReclamationApp.Business.csproj ./ReclamationApp.Business/  
COPY ReclamationApp.Entity/ReclamationApp.Entity.csproj ./ReclamationApp.Entity/  
COPY UnitTestReclamationApp/UnitTestReclamationApp.csproj ./UnitTestReclamationApp/  

COPY ReclamationApp/Global.asax.cs ./  
COPY ReclamationApp/Web.config ./  
COPY ReclamationApp.Utilities/ ./ReclamationApp.Utilities/  
COPY ReclamationApp.Business/ ./ReclamationApp.Business/  
COPY ReclamationApp.Entity/ ./ReclamationApp.Entity/  
COPY UnitTestReclamationApp/ ./UnitTestReclamationApp/  

COPY . .  
RUN nuget restore ReclamationApp/ReclamationApp.csproj  
RUN msbuild /p:Configuration=Release ReclamationApp/ReclamationApp.csproj  
EXPOSE 88  
ENTRYPOINT ["C:\\ServiceMonitor.exe", "w3svc"]  

Can anyone recommend the base image I should use to build this API? Or suggest me another solution?

4.6.1 is more than "legacy". You should really upgrade it. That alone probably will fix many problems you currently face.

You could start off one of the windows server images and install the specific version of msbuild from the dockerfile.
